# Calling thunk from react-redux-form submit handler

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-redux-form

I have this code that returns a thunk for my API

```
import { SUBSCRIBE_REQUEST, SUBSCRIBE_SUCCESS, SUBSCRIBE_FAILURE } from '../../constants'

export function subscribeUser (data) {
  return (dispatch, getState, { axios }) => {

    dispatch({ type: SUBSCRIBE_REQUEST })
    return axios.get(`some/api/call`, data)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({
          type: SUBSCRIBE_SUCCESS,
          payload: res.data
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({
          type: SUBSCRIBE_FAILURE,
          payload: error,
          error: true
        })
      })
  }
}
```

I am now implementing `react-redux-form` and am unclear on how ot connect the above with the submit function. From their docs it expects me to pass a promise in the submit action:

```
class myForm extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit (data) {
    const { dispatch } = this.props   
    dispatch(actions.submit('user', somePromise))

  }
```

Basically something like:

```
 dispatch(actions.submit('user', subscribeUser))
```

How can I connect my thunked API code with the submit handler? I've looked at `redux-promise` as a possibility though am not clear it would solve my problem and would also like to keep existing thunk codebase if I can work it.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: The example is with React-Native, but it work as React component because the reducers and actions are the same.

With `react-redux`, you can use `connect` to link the `actions` and the `props` of the `reducers` to `class` you want
With `redux` you can bind action to your action. It would look that way

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { User, Button, Header } from '../components';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';    

import * as app from '../../actions/appActions';

class Home extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.actions.load(); //This will call the actions load. this.props.action will contain subscribeUser if you declare in down mapDispatchToProps
    } }

    //Whatever the render
    render() {
        return (
          <View />
        );
    }
}
//PROPS VALIDATION
Home.propTypes = {
    users: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    actions: {
        load: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    },
};
//LINK STATE FROM REDUCER TO THIS CLASS. NEED TO DO PROPS VALIDATION
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.app.users,
    };
}

//LINK ACTIONS TO THE CLASS SO YOU CAN USE IT LIKE IF IT WAS A PROPS. NEED TO DO PROPS VALIDATION
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(app, dispatch),
    };
}

//CONNECT PROPS AND ACTION TO COMPONENT AS PROPS
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Basically, this put a Higher Order Component around the component